# passing multiple arguments to a function consisting of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I have this piece of code that I use again and again

```
ggplot(foo1, aes(x=log(area), y=log(fd), colour = id)) +
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(name = "Regions",values=cols)+
  xlab('John')+
  ylab('Peter')+
  ggtitle("xyz")+
  ggsave("x.png")
```

And I wrote this:

```
   my.function<-function(arg1,arg2,arg3){
    ggplot(arg1, aes_string(x=arg2, y=arg3, colour = id)) +
    geom_point()+
    scale_color_manual(name = "Regions",values=cols)+
    xlab('John')+
    ylab('Peter')+
    ggtitle("xyz")+
    ggsave("x.png")
  }
```

I am calling this way

```
my.function(arg1='foo1',arg2='log(area)',arg3='log(fd)')
```

But it doesn't work. I have never written functions before. I want to save the figure in every function call. Could you please help?

---

```
dput(head(foo1,4))

structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("dfa", 
"dfb", "cfa", "csb", "bsk"), class = "factor"), lon = c(-70.978611, 
-70.978611, -70.945278, -70.945278), lat = c(42.220833, 42.220833, 
42.190278, 42.190278), peakq = c(14.7531, 17.3865, 3.3414, 2.7751
), area = c(74.3327, 74.3327, 11.6549, 11.6549), fd = c(29, 54.75, 
23, 1), tp = c(14.25, 19.75, 13.5, 0.5), rt = c(14.75, 35, 9.5, 
0.5), bl = c(15485.3, 15485.3, 8242.64, 8242.64), el = c(0.643551, 
0.643551, 0.474219, 0.474219), k = c(0.325279, 0.325279, 0.176624, 
0.176624), r = c(81.947, 81.947, 38.7003, 38.7003), si = c(0.0037157, 
0.0037157, -9999, -9999), rr = c(0.00529193, 0.00529193, 0.00469513, 
0.00469513)), .Names = c("id", "lon", "lat", "peakq", "area", 
"fd", "tp", "rt", "bl", "el", "k", "r", "si", "rr"), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: First of all, you need to have `p <- ggplot` not `p <- geom_point` Secondly, is arg2 and 3 passed as a string? as in `my.function(arg1,'arg2','arg3')`? if so, change aes to aes_string. Try those two and report back

Comment: I am getting this error now: Error in aes_string(x = arg2, y = arg3, colour = id) : 
  object 'id' not found
Called from: aes_string(x = arg2, y = arg3, colour = id)
Browse[1]>

Comment: put id in quotes. also you could provide some data, that would help

Comment: Hi, why should id be in quotes? It comes from the dataframe. Not an argument.

Comment: `my.function(arg1 = foo1, arg2 = 'log(area)', arg3 = 'log(fd)')` works for me. You need `'id'` because you are using `aes_string`. I've never used ggsave as a layer so I can't comment on that. Just return the plot and save it after you run the function: `p <- function() {ggplot() + geom_point()}`

Comment: Perfect. Works now! please add answer, so that I can accept. If you are interested...

Comment: One quick question. How can I pass an argument for say xlab? I would like to send a name. Not sure due to the ' '.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
my.function<-function(arg1,arg2,arg3){
    ggplot(arg1, aes_string(x=arg2, y=arg3, colour ="id")) +
    geom_point()+
    scale_color_manual(name = "Regions",values=cols)+
    xlab('John')+
    ylab('Peter')+
    ggtitle("xyz")+
    ggsave("x.png")
}
```

and you call it with

```
my.function(arg1=foo1,arg2='log(area)',arg3='log(fd)')
```

Note that now you're passing the data.frame itself, not the name of the data.frame as a string. And since you're passing the column names as strings, you need to pass everything in `aes_string` as strings.

If you really want to pass the data.frame names as a string, you can change the first `ggplot()` call to

```
ggplot(get(arg1), aes_string(x=arg2, y=arg3, colour ="id")) +
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. One quick question. How can I pass an argument for say xlab? I would like to send a name.

Comment: @GeekunaMatata Add arg4 as a parameter to your function, then change `xlab('John')+` to `xlab(arg4)+`

Comment: Could you please take a look at this as well? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664448/how-can-i-fix-this-ggplot-function